# Command to execute to create signed url using service account for Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'd like to create `signed url` using service account for Cloud Function. I was able to do it from my gcloud instance, but I'm not quite sure if it is also possible to do the same in Cloud Function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes,  it's possible. What did you try? In which language? What didn't work?

Comment: @masterbyte any progress? Can you please provide us above information?